# PyCharm: Refactor-Extract-Method not found via ctrl-shift-a

Tags: pycharm

First I mark a block of code in PyCharm.

Then I want to do "Refactor: Extract Method".

I type ctrl-shift-a to search over all available actions.

I enter "ref met" but "Refactor: Extract Method" does not get found.

I know that I could use ctrl-alt-m, but *ctrl-shift-a and "ref met"* feels more natural for me.

How to access "Refactor: Extract Method" via ctrl-shift-a?

The work-around via "Refactor this" and the second pop-up is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be shortened to `Method...`. On the Mac, I type <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, the search dialog shows up, and all I have to type is `Met` and hit return (that is sufficiently unique in my environment) and up pops the `Extract Method` dialog box.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I think this is a bug. I created an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28148 thank you!

Comment: I thought it was weird that it didn't have the word "Extract" in it - I just had to type different words until it came up.